# Stored procedure and where type in P, U, PC

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I'm beginner in SQL. I can't find what is this line:

```
type in (N'P', N'PC')
```

What is in where clause: P, PC, U?

EDIT:

The full query is:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
             FROM sys.objects 
            WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].SP_AUTHENTIFICATION]') 
              AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off what Relational Database Management System?

However, I suspect that `type` is a column in a table or a variable in your stored procedure.

`N`, implies that you're converting the next string to a `nchar`, `nvarchar` or `nvarchar2` (depending on RDBMS). These are data-types that allow multi-byte characters.

`'PC'` and `'P'` are strings.

Putting this all together you're converting `'PC'` and `'P'`  to a multi-byte character set and checking whether the column or variable `type` is the same as one of these strings.

`in` means that `type` can be the same as *either* `'PC'` *or* `'P'`.

---

From your comment you're using SQL-Server

You're checking whether the object `[dbo].[SP_AUTHENTIFICATION]` exists and is a stored procedure (P) or a assembly stored procedure (PC).

The column `type` in `sys.objects` is not an `nchar` so the conversion is fairly pointless.

Going point by point

- `IF EXISTS` - If the result of the following query in brackets returns a row:
- `SELECT * FROM sys.objects` - Select a row from `sys.objects`
- `WHERE object_id =` - Where the `object_id` is equal to the following
- `OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[SP_AUTHENTIFICATION]')` - Return the `object_id` of `[dbo].[SP_AUTHENTIFICATION]`
- `AND type in (N'P', N'PC')` - and where that object is a stored procedure.

`U`, which isn't in your query is checking to see whether the `type` is a table. [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx) gives you a full list.

Comment: This line is from here: `IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[SP_AUTHENTIFICATION]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))` What is this line? Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

If you want your question to be useful for other people, the detail from the comment belongs to the body of the question, as these identifiers are only meaningful in the context of the `sysobjects` table.

Here are the meanings.

- U - user table
- P - traditional stored procedure (SQL)
- PC - CLR stored procedure (usually C# or VB.NET)

Your clause therefore checks whether any procedure called `sp_authetication` exists.

Comment: And `sys.objects`. `sysobjects` is a backward compatibility view and shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 0):

The 'line' is looking for a stored procedure named SP_AUTHENTIFICATION and likely dropping it if it exists.  This is quite common in SQL Server because SQL Server does not have CreateOrAlter.

I found a better way to perform a CreateOrAlter so that history is maintained on the stored procedure.

```
if not exists(SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[myproc]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
  exec('create proc dbo.myproc as select 0')

alter proc dbo.myproc

as

...
```