# What is the purpose and use of "AND type in (N'P', N'PC')" in sql stored procedures?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I am new to creating stored procedures and I saw this sql below in an existing stored procedure:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'stored_proc_name') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE 'stored_proc_name' Go
```

After some investigating I did, I found that we are using N for any unicode characters that may be present. However, I am not sure why we are using "type in (N'P', N'PC')"?

Can anyone please explain this construct?

Also just confirm if I am correct in my thinking about the use of N here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the N means that the strings are unicode.

What else you have is the `in` operator, i.e. `n in (n, ...)` where the first operand is the field `type` and the values in the parentheses are two unicode strings.

So, it has the same meaning as `and (type = N'P' or type = N'PC')`.

Comment: same meaning, but they work very different, 'in' works much more effectively

Answer (score 8):

To add in to the other answers:

You're checking whether the object [dbo].[sp_NAME] exists and is a stored procedure (P) or a assembly stored procedure (PC).

Here is an example of what we use:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[sp_NAME]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_NAME]
GO
```

Here is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774059/stored-procedure-and-where-type-in-p-u-pc) with answers.

For information on an [assembly stored procedure.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190790%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The "N" is a Microsoft way of expressing a constant, unicode string (2-bytes/character rather than 1/byte per character).  Some built-in functions and stored procedures require it.

The "P" and "PC" specify the types of objects.

Comment: "Unicode data types take twice as much storage space as non-Unicode data types" - which includes MBCS. As a result, Unicode is often 4 bytes per glyph.

Comment: @egrunin . . . interesting.  Everything in SQL Server suggests that it uses two bytes to store Unicode.  I wonder how that implementation works with the standard.  I learned something.